# Magento Product Detail Page doesn't fully load and description and options are missing

Tags: magento-1.9

I've flushed the cache on my browser and inside Magento, re-indexed and even tried to recreate products but eventually they always stop showing the description and options.

It doesn't do it on all products but it keeps doing it in the same products no matter how many times I duplicate or recreate new ones.

It seems RWD theme is just not working the way it used to with previous deployments. I am in Magento 1.9.3.7.

Comment: Do you see the footer?

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in `var/log/system.log`?

Comment: Please try to check the product page in base default theme.

Answer (score 0):

Open your magento view.phtml file and cut content codes from that file and then paste step by step then you can find easily error in which section you are facing problem.
File path of view.phtml is => 
app\design\frontend\your_theme\default\template\catalog\product

and check below screenshot, if the error is in code then you can easily find.

[image]